# How to add <style> tag in Vue.js component

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm on Vue.js v2. I have a CSS stylesheet stored as a string in a variable.

```
import sitePackCss from '!!raw-loader!sass-loader!../../app/javascript/styles/site.sass';
```

I need to create a  tag from my component.

```
<style v-html="sitePackCss" />
```

OR

```
<style>{sitePackCss}</style>
```

When I do either of these, I get the following error in the console:

```
Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed.
```

How do I get this  tag onto the page?

NOTE: I know this is a hacky, non-preferred way to include styles. This solution will only get used in the context of storybook, where I need to include specific CSS files for specific stories (without storybook/webpack adding them to every story). If I use normal webpack loaders, each  tag is added to *every* story. Importing the styles as a string is the only way I've found to sidestep that behavior.

Comment: What about `import '!!raw-loader!sass-loader!../../app/javascript/styles/site.sass';` inside the main.js file?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The whole point of this hack is to _not_ include the css globally to every story and what you suggested would definitely do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the style to the `src` tag of the style in your SFC :

```html
<style lang="sass" src="../../app/javascript/styles/site.sass">

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work!

```
import sitePackCss from '!!raw-loader!sass-loader!../../app/javascript/styles/site.sass';
```

In template:

```
<component is="style" type="text/css">${sitePackCss}</component>
```

Note: the sass files have references to fonts that were not working correctly using this technique. I had to update the staticDirs config  to make those paths work. https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets